# Passing a list as an argument, but keeping default values

Tags: python, arrays

I'm currently trying to use a list with default values through it. I would like to be able to pass a single value into the array, as the first element, and retain the rest of the default values.

ex:

```
def message_return(messages = [" ", " ", " "])
    return messages

print(message_return(["test"]))
```

Ideally I would would want `messages` to print `["test", " ", " "]`

However it always fully overwrites `messages` and prints out `["test"]`.

Is there anyway I can retain the default values of the list without having to pass `["test", " ", " "]`
every time I only had one message to pass through?

Comment: Don't use mutable default arguments. A new list won't be created between calls of `message_return`. Use `*args`  and/or `**kwargs` instead.

Comment: Make messages = [ '','','' ] a variable in your function, then for the message_return pass in args like chrisitan said, then for the amount of element in the array being passed in, fill the array?

Comment: I agree with comment before, just use packing list, change ur parameter to `def msg(*args) ` and u can call the function with `msg("test1") `, args will pack the argument with list type.

Comment: Hmm okay, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Set `messages` to `None`. If something is passed in, then `messages` will be set to whatever's passed in plus the items in `default_messages` which come after the length of the array passed in. Else, `messages` is `default_messages`.

```py
def message_return(messages=None):
    default_messages = [" ", " ", " "]
    if messages is not None:
        messages = messages + default_messages[len(messages):]
    else:
        messages = default_messages.copy()
    return messages

print(message_return(["test"])) # ['test', ' ', ' ']
```