# Why is my class member shared among objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class CoolList:

    def __init__(self, list=[]):
        self._list = list

    def append(self, item:str):
        self._list.append(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = CoolList()
    b = CoolList()
    a.append("test")
    print(a._list)
    print(b._list)
    # output: 
    # ['test']
    # ['test']
```

I have two objects of `CoolList`, `a` and `b`.

`_list` is not a static class member.

But when I append an item into `a`,

`b` also gets that item.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Do not use mutables as default arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905366/passing-a-list-as-an-argument-but-keeping-default-values

Link to Python Docs for default args: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values